# MongoDB search all document with lat and lng in polygon

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, mongodb-query, polygon

i was reading at that [tutorial](http://uhftopic.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/mongodb-and-google-maps-mash-up-for-polygon-search/) to see how get documents that has position inside a polygon given by google maps polygon drawer.

In that tutorial it stores the position in an array like:

```
pos:{lat:xxx,lng:yyy}
```

That is not my case because in my documents that value are stored like:

```
{...
"hotel_lat":"xxx",
"hotel_lng":"yyy",
...
},
{...
"hotel_lat":"xxx",
"hotel_lng":"yyy",
...
},
{...
"hotel_lat":"xxx",
"hotel_lng":"yyy",
...
},
...
```

So in the tutorial it uses that query to find all documents in polygon:

```
$query = array("pos" => array(
               '$within' => array('$polygon' => $poly)));
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

I change it in:

```
$query = array(
array("hotel_lat","hotel_lng") => array(
'$within' => array('$polygon' => $poly)))
```

but it gives me that error: `Illegal offset type in.....`

What could be the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before hunting down further tutorials, which I gather you have done in this case because you wanted something written with PHP, the MongoDB site has the basic tutorial information that you need:

> http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2d-index/

And before you say, "This is not PHP" then look at the code below:

```php
$result = '{"$pos": { "$within": { "$polygon": "$poly" } } }';
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
```

With the output

```php
stdClass Object
(
    [$pos] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$within] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$polygon] => $poly
                )

        )

)
```

So that gives you an idea of how to write this in PHP. And the reverse is true to convert to JSON and see if your coded form is right.

So the code you have actually written, isn't even a valid structure for PHP, let alone being way off the required syntax.

In the [core documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) it is explained what your storage **must** look like, and that the preferred form in MongoDB storage is the **array** form, in order to consistently maintain the order across languages that may not be able to maintain the required order of a 
**hash**:

```js
pos : [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
```

You **cannot** have two separate fields for the "longitude" and "latitude" values, as MongoDB **cannot** create the required Geo-spatial index over multiple fields. Should you have managed to **receive** your data where the values where in discreet fields, then it is up to you to *re-shape* that data for the correct storage requirements for MongoDB.

Please read through all the [**MongoDB** documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) first, before moving on to other tutorial tasks. *Fix* your data so that it is in a correct format, and *index* the required field. Then you can work with Geo-spatial queries.

And please use `json_encode` and `json_decode` regularly during your development process, as it is a very clear way to compare to documentation samples and *visualize* that you are doing things right:

```php
$poly = array();
array_push(
  $poly, floatval(51.52081391707402), floatval(-0.12737274169921875),
  floatval(51.487582985843034), floatval(-0.13578414916992188));

$test = array("pos" => array('$within' => array('$polygon' => $poly)));
echo json_encode( $test, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) ."\n"
```

Resulting in:

```js
{
    "pos": {
        "$within": {
            "$polygon": [
                51.520813917074,
                -0.12737274169922,
                51.487582985843,
                -0.13578414916992
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As a JSON representation of how the structure is **actually** transmitted to the server converted as BSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for response! I convert my field to match mongoDB index and all is working good. Thank you again!